# How to add custom js file to each page of specific entity CRUD in laravel-backpack

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to add a specific js file to a page of specific entity crud. (example: I want to add `Tag-insert.js` to the insert page of `Tag` crud)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a widget to insert custom javascript in the crud page.

Check out the docs for widgets. Focus on [after_scripts](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/base-widgets#creating-a-custom-widget-type) section.

Example:
you can create `fooCrud.blade.php` in `resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/widgets` that the blade file contains your custom javascript like this:

```
@push('after_scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('packages/backpack/crud/js/foo/foo-crud.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

then you can add this widget on your desire page, like this:

Add the following code to desire `setupCreateOperation()` function in specific CRUD controller:

```
$this->data['widgets']['after_content'] = [
 [
   'type' => 'fooCrud' // name of widget
 ]
];
```